# Bar chart of pandas multiindex: stack first level

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a pandas dataframe, with MultiIndex:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

multi_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
                                       ['a1', 'a2', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'c']])

index = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']


data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (len(index), len(multi_idx))),
                    index=index, columns=multi_idx)


       A     B        C
      a1 a2 b1 b2 b3  c
one    6  8  6  4  9  5
two    6  9  7  7  4  9
three  3  2  5  8  2  6
four   1  7  0  9  2  7
```

I want to represent the data as a bar chart that with stacked bars within each label of first level of columns [A, B, C].

So my desired output is a single chart with:

- 4 groups of bars (one per index)
- 3 bars within each group [A, B, C]
- each bar being the stacked values for subgroups (e.g. [a1, a2] for A)

This is a schematic representation of my desired output, just to clarify how I want to group/stack the variables (labels are for illustration only...)

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47494557)